# Undefined object when i want to query data

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to query and post all of the user (with loop) that i have from firebase. I push the user as object with id from auth. But when i want to query aall of user i got a problem as undefine. here is the code :

```
this.db.object('/user/'+'/').subscribe(data => {
      this.fullname = data.fullname;
    })
    console.log(this.fullname);
  }
```

and this is what i do in html to show all of the fullname from user

```
{{fullname}}
```

this is the structure on firebase

[image: firebase structure]

Comment: is fullname undefined?

Comment: yes fullname is undefined, i want to get the fullname of all user

Comment: Do you have access to ID? Try like this {{fullName?}}